# Ruby: Error: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) when I give the right number of arguments

Tags: ruby, class, methods, arguments

**Here is the class file:**

```
class HealthProfile
    attr_reader :firstName, :lastName, :gender, :birthYear, :currentYear, :height, :weight
    attr_writer :firstName, :lastName, :gender, :birthYear, :currentYear, :height, :weight

def initialize(firstName, lastName, gender, birthYear, currentYear, height, weight)
    @firstName = firstName
    @lastName = lastName
    @gender = gender
    @birthYear = birthYear
    @currentYear = currentYear
    @height = height
    @weight = weight
end


def userAge(currentYear, birthYear)
    age = currentYear - birthYear
    return age
end


def maxHeartRate(age) #The maximum heart rate is computed as 220 minus age in years
    maxhr = 220 - age
    return maxhr
end

def targetHeartRateRange(maxhr) #The target-heart-rate is a range that is 50-89% of the maximum heart rate
    lowtarget = 0.50 * maxhr
    hightarget = 0.89 * maxhr
    return lowtarget, hightarget
end


def BMI(weight, height) #(weight:lbs * 703) / (height:inches * height:inches)
    bmi = (weight * 703) / (height * height)
    return bmi
end

def displayHealthProfile(firstName, lastName, gender, age, height, weight, maxhr, lowtarget, hightarget, bmi)
    puts ("HEALTH PROFILE FOR: #{firstName lastName}")
    puts ("***********************************")
    puts
    puts ("Gender: #{gender}")
    puts ("Age: #{age}")
    puts ("Height (in inches): #{height}")
    puts ("Weight (in pounds): #{weight}")
    puts ("Maximum heart rate: #{maxhr}")
    puts
    puts
    puts ("Target heart rate range")
    puts ("*************************")
    puts
    puts ("Minimum: #{lowtarget}")
    puts ("Maximum: #{hightarget}")
    puts ("BMI: #{bmi}")
    puts
    puts
    puts ("BMI VALUES")
    puts ("************")
    puts
    puts ("Underweight: less than 18.5")
    puts ("Normal: between 18.5 and 24.9")
    puts ("Overweight: between 25 and 29.9")
    puts ("Obese: 30 or greater")
end
end
```

**Here is the main file code:**

```
require_relative 'lab11class.rb'
require 'date'

currentYear = Date.today.year
currentYear = currentYear.to_i()

print ("Enter your First Name: ")
firstName = gets()
print ("Enter your Last Name: ")
lastName = gets()
print ("Enter your gender (Male/Female): ")
gender = gets()
print ("Enter your year of birth: ")
birthYear = gets().to_i()
print ("Enter your height in inches: ")
height = gets().to_i()
print ("Enter your weight in pounds: ")
weight = gets().to_i()

hp = HealthProfile.new(firstName, lastName, gender, birthYear, currentYear,     height, weight)
age = hp.userAge(currentYear, birthYear)
maxhr = hp.maxHeartRate(age)
lowtarget, hightarget = hp.targetHeartRateRange(maxhr)
bmi = hp.BMI(weight, height)
hp.displayHealthProfile(firstName, lastName, gender, age, height, weight, maxhr, lowtarget, hightarget, bmi)
```

**Here is the full error**

```
lab11class.rb:40:in `displayHealthProfile': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
```

The problem is apparently with the displayHealthProfile method. It should expect 10 arguments, but when I enter all 10 in the main file it gives the error.
However, if I remove one or more of the arguments from the call in the main file, I get the error except it says (given 9, expected 10) and so on if I were to remove more.
Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I have fixed it and the program is working properly. The problem wasn't with the method at all, displayHealthProfile was correctly defined. The problem was with the firstName and lastName variables that were the first ones used under the method. The two variables were parsed with newline characters which didn't sit well with the method call. So here are the changes that fixed it.

**Original**

```
puts ("HEALTH PROFILE FOR: #{firstName lastName}")
```

**Changed To:**

```
puts ("HEALTH PROFILE FOR: #{firstName.chomp} #{lastName.chomp}")
```

Thanks for your responses!

Comment: the line number in the error (40) doesn't match with the actual line number in the code (25)

Comment: Why does `displayHealthProfile` need any arguments at all? Shouldn't everything it needs in the instance variables? Also, be very careful with your parentheses, `m (arg)` and `m(arg)` are very different things in Ruby, they may work the same with one argument but the parentheses in the first are for expression grouping while in the second they are for calling the method; the difference becomes apparent when you have multiple arguments (i.e. `m(a, b)` is fine but `m (a, b)` is a syntax error).

Comment: I removed some of my comment lines at the top of the file so the line is 40 where the method displayHealthProfile is defined in my file. And the variables that the method needs are created in the main file so unless I make them universal using $ then they need to be passed into the method if i’m not mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In line 2, you define `firstName` as a method with zero arguments:

```
attr_reader :firstName
```

(That's what a reader method is: a method that takes no arguments.)

Here, you call `firstName` with one argument:

```
puts ("HEALTH PROFILE FOR: #{firstName lastName}")
```

Ruby allows you to leave out the parentheses around the argument list, which means that

```
firstName lastName
```

(as in the string substitution) is the same as

```
self.firstName(lastName)
```

What you probably mean is:

```
puts ("HEALTH PROFILE FOR: #{firstName} #{lastName}")
#                                     ↑ ↑↑
```

> The two variables were parsed with newline characters which didn't sit well with the method call.

This doesn't have anything to do with newlines in the strings. The content of a string *cannot possibly* cause this error. The error was caused by the fact that you called `firstName` with one argument but defined it with zero.

Answer (score -1):

In health_profile.rb

```
class HealthProfile
  def initialize(firstName, lastName, gender, birthYear, currentYear, height, weight)
    @firstName = firstName
    @lastName = lastName
    @gender = gender
    @birthYear = birthYear
    @currentYear = currentYear
    @height = height
    @weight = weight
  end

  def userAge
    @currentYear - @birthYear
  end

  def maxHeartRate #The maximum heart rate is computed as 220 minus age in years
    220 - userAge
  end

  def targetHeartRateRange #The target-heart-rate is a range that is 50-89% of the maximum heart rate
    maxhr = maxHeartRate
    lowtarget = 0.50 * maxhr
    hightarget = 0.89 * maxhr
    [lowtarget, hightarget]
  end

  def bmi #(weight:lbs * 703) / (height:inches * height:inches)
    (@weight * 703) / (@height * @height)
  end

  def displayHealthProfile
    lowtarget, hightarget = targetHeartRateRange

    puts "HEALTH PROFILE FOR: #{@firstName.chomp} #{@lastName}"
    puts "***********************************"
    puts
    puts "Gender: #{@gender}"
    puts "Age: #{userAge}"
    puts "Height (in inches): #{@height}"
    puts "Weight (in pounds): #{@weight}"
    puts "Maximum heart rate: #{maxHeartRate}"
    puts
    puts
    puts "Target heart rate range"
    puts "*************************"
    puts
    puts "Minimum: #{lowtarget}"
    puts "Maximum: #{hightarget}"
    puts "BMI: #{bmi}"
    puts
    puts
    puts "BMI VALUES"
    puts "************"
    puts
    puts "Underweight: less than 18.5"
    puts "Normal: between 18.5 and 24.9"
    puts "Overweight: between 25 and 29.9"
    puts "Obese: 30 or greater"
  end
end
```

In main.rb

```
require_relative 'health_profile.rb'
require 'date'

currentYear = Date.today.year
currentYear = currentYear.to_i()

print ("Enter your First Name: ")
firstName = gets()
print ("Enter your Last Name: ")
lastName = gets()
print ("Enter your gender (Male/Female): ")
gender = gets()
print ("Enter your year of birth: ")
birthYear = gets().to_i()
print ("Enter your height in inches: ")
height = gets().to_i()
print ("Enter your weight in pounds: ")
weight = gets().to_i()

hp = HealthProfile.new(firstName, lastName, gender, birthYear, currentYear, height, weight)
hp.displayHealthProfile
```

Then

```
ruby main.rb
```

Comment: I have removed all arguments and returns from the methods inside the class and changed the main code to what you suggested. Now I am getting unused variable warnings as well as the original error even though there are no arguments passed to the displayHealthProfile method now.

Comment: @DanielLoschiavo  Why the downvote? The answer above does exactly what you need in a clean way.

Comment: Did not mean to, was trying to upvote but still said zero so i hit all of them and realized it doesnt show under 15. Not sure how to remove it. @RohitNamjoshi

Comment: @DanielLoschiavo Oh well. If my answer worked for you then you can accept it as the best answer.